# Nuxt.js: How move Global CSS from style tag to css file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I'm confused with the Nuxt.js SCSS compilation...
I have the **assets** folder and it has two SCSS files included in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
  // Global CSS (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css)
  css: [
    '~assets/scss/bootstrap.scss',
    '~assets/scss/main.scss'
  ],
```

Launch `npm run build` and then `npm run generate`, then I go into the **dist** folder and open the **index.html** file, what I see is all css (and it is too big) inside the **style** tag on the page:

[image: Global CSS in the style tag]

Nuxt.js has compiled the SCSS files from assets and put CSS in the style tag.
How put into a file and connect with link tag in the head section like this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

You may say I can use **head** settings in `nuxt.config.js`, but I cannot because it is possible only with remote and static files, it does not work like this:

```
head: {
  meta: [
    { charset: 'utf-8' },
    { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no' },
    { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
  ],
  link: [
    { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '~/assets/scss/bootstrap.scss' },
    { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '~/assets/scss/main.scss' },
    { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/svg+xml', href: '/images/logo.svg' },
  ],
  script: []
},
```

I did not find in the Nuxt.js documentation how put the Global CSS to a file. Is it possible with Nuxt.js config or change the Webpack build config only? Help me understand please :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`extractCSS`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#extractcss) build option to extract all your CSS assets into separate files (usually one per component) and allows you to put in cache each CSS file:

```js
// nuxt.config.js

export default {
  build: {
    extractCSS: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Dat works! I'll be read the docs more accurately. thanks for the answer and the doc link.

Comment: I'm wondering if there are some issues with it being set to `true` as a default because this one seems to be really nice and with no drawbacks.

Comment: The drawback is that the users browser has to make multiple network requests.