# Nuxt: how to have css global styles in files rather than inside of a style tag

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have added css in my nuxt application like this:

```js
css: [
    '@/assets/scss/custom.scss',
    '@/assets/css/master.css',
    '@/assets/css/main.css',
    '@/assets/css/svg.css',
    '@/assets/css/all.min.css',
    '@/assets/css/vue-paginate.css',
    '@/node_modules/vue2-datepicker/index.css',
    '@/assets/css/vue-tooltip.css',
    '@/node_modules/vue-select/dist/vue-select.css',
    '@/node_modules/vue-file-agent/dist/vue-file-agent.css',
    '@/node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css',
    '@/node_modules/vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css',
    '@/node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css',
    '@/assets/css/client-style.less',
  ],
```

Whenever I try to view the page source it is showing me all the css included
[image]

So, Is there a way to include these css as a link in the all of the pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `css` property is used for this exact purpose

> Nuxt.js lets you define the CSS files/modules/libraries you want to set globally (included in every page)

If you want to include it per page or component, include your styles in the `<style>` tag.

---

If you want them split into files, I guess that you could use [`extractCSS`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#extractcss)

```js
export default {
  build: {
    extractCSS: true,
    // or
    extractCSS: {
      ignoreOrder: true
    }
  }
}
```

---

Same question as yours as far as I understand: [Nuxt.js: How move Global CSS from style tag to css file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66175833/8816585)

Comment: Thanks!! it is working great but in firefox it is still the same issue. Is this kind of it's limitation?

Comment: @MohitChandani try to see if it's not a cache issue (open a private window in Firefox). There is no reason that this will not work on Firefox specifically.

Comment: yeess in private window the issue is resolved. Should I clear my firefox cache?